# One Mac can print to network printer, one cannot

Tags: macbook-pro, network, macos, printing

I have a mid-2010 Macbook Pro running El Capitan (IP: 192.168.1.65) and a newer Macbook Air (~2014) (IP: 192.168.1.71) running El Capitan. Both are connected wirelessly to the same network: a U-Verse router (IP: 192.168.1.254). I have an Okidata MC362W (IP: 192.168.1.78) wired to the U-Verse router. All on a subnet of 255.255.255.0. The Macbook Air can print using CUPS without issue. The Macbook Pro prints OK until it doesn't also using CUPS and the Internet Printing Protocol. Then it will stop seeing the IP address. If I reboot the U-Verse, which takes more than 5 minutes, the Macbook Pro can then usually see the printer again until the same issue comes around 4 or 5 days later.

Here's what I've done:

- I've assigned a static IP to the printer. The Macbook Pro is not
  using the same IP and it is not using the same IP of anything else on the network.
- I've manually repaired permissions on the Macbook
  Pro
- I've reset the printer settings on the MBP to default
- I updated the firmware on the OKIDATA
- I've uninstalled and re-installed the printer multiple times
- I've installed the most up-to-date drivers for the printer
- I've tried to print using Airprint -- it can see the
  printer, it cannot connect to the printer
- I cannot ping the printer from the MBP nor can I access its IP through the browser.
- To the best of my ability, the network setup on the Macbook Air and the MBP are
  identical

Does anyone have any suggestions of something new to try? TIA.

Comment: What IP's are in use locally?  Please edit into your question the local IP's of both MacBooks, the printer, and the router.  Subnet masks also especially anywhere you've set a static ip.

Comment: @Tyson I've added the IP addresses in the question.

Comment: The printer and MB are both .78? Or is that a typo?

Comment: Typo, already fixed. Sorry. One is .71, other is .78.

Comment: How did you assign the static address to the Okidata?

Comment: I assigned the static address on the OKIDATA through settings and also on the router.

Comment: The IP's should work, as shown then... Not the problem I had in mind...

Comment: So, you set it in two places?  What about the lease pool?  Does your static IP assignment and your DHCP pool overlap in anyway?

Comment: That's a good question, @Allan. I think I understand what you're getting at but I have not adjusted the pool at all. On the U-Verse I was able to change it for the device it had already identified -- so since I didn't want to have it re-assign one, I changed the option to "Private Fixed" and it currently says "Connected DHCP". Maybe that's not the same as setting it in two places ... ?

Comment: Check to see what the pool is.  Limit it to 50 or so addresses; like .100 to .149 - then statically assign your OKI to .50 or something well outside the pool.  I am assuming the message you are seeing from the OKI - if so, it's still getting a DHCP address

Comment: OK, I'll give that a try. Thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: Make sure you have the relevant drivers for your printer installed on the MacBook that can't print.

Comment: @Allan I think your answer has solved my problem if you want to make it an answer I will mark it as correct. (Sorry for the delay -- my intermittent problem meant I didn't try to ACTUALLY fix it for a long time.)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem on my Mac. It was McAfee's firewall. It was blocking Bonjour communications... hence no printer sharing, or finding on the network. Disabled McAfee's firewall, and poof! Everything works.